# Viability of recent Hebrew Language related question

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15234/759) was recently asked on the main site.

The [FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) says:

> On the other hand, questions unrelated to Jewish life and learning, even if they are about...
>
> > other religions
> >     Hebrew language
> >     Jews, Jewish history, and Israel
>
> ...are generally off-topic.

I voted to close as out of scope because I think this question falls in the category of Hebrew Language. Apparently only two other people agreed with me as there are currently only 3 close votes.

Can someone from the majority camp explain why they thought this question was in scope? I know many people have seen it based on the multiple answers and comments, yet they chose not to close. Why?

Comment: I really, really think that question belongs on Mi.Yodeya (a priori). Moving away from the technicalities and arguments for a bit, doesn't it seem that way to you? I think our rules should be edited to allow for such a thing.

Comment: ...Perhaps, for a start, we could allow *meta-level* language questions, like this one. But I think the ideal would be a more holistic/subtle tweak to the scope. Not that I can propose one. :-[

Comment: @SAH I am very comfortable with the current policies here. You are welcome to propose any changes you want here on meta, and I as a user will thus likely oppose those changes. (I as a moderator will try to only enforce the community consensus.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

It's partially about the ability of an Israeli to understand Tanach.

Comment: I'm not sure Israeli Arabs care much about Jewish Life and Learning...

Comment: @DoubleAA: Being Israeli is not the JL&L part. Understanding Tanach is the JL&L part.

Comment: I declined to vote to close because it's about understanding Tanach, which is a little iffy on its own but combined with the poster being new user it tipped me over.  In principle we shouldn't treat new users differently in this regard, and if it were clearly off-topic I would vote to close, but I tend to give the benefit of the doubt -- specially since this means declining to act, rather than acting.  (I also didn't up-vote, for instance.)

Comment: @msh210 If someone asked about how muslims or christians understand tanach would that be in scope? Seemingly not. There is nothing Jewish about this question. It's asking how well people with language skills in modern hebrew can handle reading biblical hebrew. there's nothing Jewish about that.

Comment: @DoubleAA, good point! Subtract one (my implied upvote as poster) from the count for this answer.

Comment: @msh210 I have -1 the answer on your behalf.

Comment: @DoubleAA, re "I have -1 the answer on your behalf", since you (seemingly) disagree with it, why didn't you −1 it on your own behalf?

Comment: @msh210 Because my thoughts on the matter were clear from the question. I was letting the community indicate their thoughts through the voting.